# Twitter bootstrap wizard skip steps during onnext

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

This is a specific question to twitter bootstrap http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/

I am trying to work out if anyone has been able to skip steps when handling the onNext event. I want to skip steps depending on inputs that have been selected on previous steps. I have seen you can do this:

```js
$('#rootwizard .finish').click(function() {
    alert('Finished!, Starting over!');
    $('#rootwizard').find("a[href*='tab1']").trigger('click');
});
```

I can't use this as I have disabled the tabs, and this unfortunately doesn't help if I use this during the onNext event if I have enabled the tabs as it continues to executes the code from the onNext event caller.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: There is an $el.bootstrapWizard('show', tab) method which I use. This is an old question though, maybe you've got it handled already.

Answer (score 3):

simply  you can use

```
_myWizard.bootstrapWizard('show', 6);// zero-bazed index
```

and `_myWizard` is what returned from `bootstrapWizard initialisation`

```
var _myWizard=$('#AddMemberWizard').bootstrapWizard({
    'tabClass': 'form-wizard',
    'onNext': function (tab, navigation, index) {
            .....
         }
});
```

hope this helps you